# Laravel 5.x. Throwing Manual error from form validations

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, laravel-5

Is there any way to throw a manual form validation error in laravel. Let's say there's a function that allows to check a credit card's number and if that fails I want to set an error and redirect the user back to the form. I'm looking for something like.

```
private function validateCreditCard() {...}
if (!validateCreditCard()) {
    # Throw a form validation error here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually many ways of validating in Laravel.

1. From Controller

```html
Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'ccv' => 'required|numeric|max:3',
        'card_number' => 'required',
     'expiry_date' => 'required',
 ])->validate();
```

2. Specify where you want to redirect request to explictly in your code

```html
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'ccv' => 'required|numeric',
            'card_number' => 'required',
             'expiry_date' => 'required',

            
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('pay/with/creditcard')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

3. Do another validation after the first validation e.g (check if card is debitable)

```html
$validator = Validator::make(
                'ccv' => 'required|numeric',
                'card_number' => 'required',
                 'expiry_date' => 'required',); //your normal validation here. e.g  ccv, required fields etc.
    
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        if (!$this->validateCreditCard()) { //do another validation e.g check if card is debitable
        
            $validator->errors()->add('credit_card', 'Something is wrong with this credit card!');
        }
    });
```

And you can redirect back to payment form. Let's assume your route is '`pay/with/creditcard`'

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('pay/with/creditcard')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you can run it in controller

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful.